# Can someone explain what Hash Functions do in the most simplest form?

Tags: encryption, hash

I'm tired of explaining it to my fellow computer science friends at university without getting too technical. Is there are a more simpler way of explaining?

Comment: They produce a (hopefully) mathematically irreversible string which is (1) consistently reproduced by the same input string and (2) not produced by any other input string.

Comment: (1) is good, (2) is sloppy.

Comment: A hash function is a many-to-one function that takes a variable length input and produces a fixed length output.  Ideally a small change to the input produces a large change to the output.  For cryptographic use the function should not be easily reversible, though this is not required for other uses, such as hash tables.

Comment: Have they discovered [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) at your university?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, and it is unclear what part of the usual definitions you do not understand.

Comment: Note that you've tagged this *encryption* and hash. As hashing is not encryption, I'm not sure you're the one that should explain. Hashing is [cryptography](https://cryptography.stackexchange.com), not encryption.